# Can't use dotenv with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, dotenv

I am moving an Express app across from CommonJS `require` syntax to the ES6 module `import` syntax. This is fine until I try and use `dotenv` to load my environment variables and every time I try to access these variables they come back as undefined.

app.js

```
// importing environmental variables
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import express from 'express';

let x = process.env.David;
console.log(x);
```

.env

```
David = test
```

Comment: Show us the commonJS syntax you are trying to convert

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try putting the env config in a separate file and import it first.

```
// loadEnv.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()


// index.js
import './loadEnv';
import express from 'express';
let x = process.env.David;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I'm glad to help @DavidMulholland. Please consider to accept this or any other answer that worked for you.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: it does not work for me :(

Comment: @samuelnihoul This works because the *loadEnv.js* module code is executed before the *express.js* module code. Assuming, of course, that it is imported before that.

Answer (score 41):

```
import "dotenv/config.js";
```

For `.env` variables across all files use the above.

Comment: this is the easiest way to do it, good job

Comment: Notice that in many cases you want to put this import statement before ALL other import statements in your index.js / main.ts / entry point file. This can eliminate problems with common frameworks such as NestJS.

Answer (score 2):

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import "dotenv/config.js";
    
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

dotenv.config({path:`${__dirname}/.env`});
```

I did this because my .env file was inside src folder **(projectName/src/.env)** and it was not detected by dotenv. But actually it's easier move .env file to the project folder **(projectName/.env)** and use:

```
import "dotenv/config.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // importing environmental variables
        import express from 'express';
        import { config } from "dotenv";
        config({ path: process.ENV })
            
        let x = process.env.David;
        console.log(x);
```

Comment: You could improve your answer with an explanation of your code

Comment: path is a string and ProcessEnv is not, this is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to call `dotenv` **only once** in the entire application,
as was possible in `commonjs` with `require`.

In particular, in case you want to change the config, such as changing the PATH like this:
`config({ path: '../.env' })`

You must write a separate file, like this:

```
// env.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });
```

Then import the `env.js` file in the main file like this:

```
// index.js
/** Import first before calling other files */
import './env.js';
import sqlConnect from './sql'
import express from 'express';

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

**Note!**
Import first before calling other files in the application.

Since in ES6 the `import` is performed before the code is executed.
You can see more here:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can just use `import 'dotenv/config';` as per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import)

Answer (score 0):

Stop using dotenv in Node.js v20.6.0+
Like this:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

Instead use this on your run command:

```
node --env-file=.env app.mjs
```

Source: https://medium.com/@tony.infisical/stop-using-dotenv-in-node-js-v20-6-0-8febf98f6314