# Can't access .env file

Tags: node.js, express, .env

I can't access .env file from anywhere other than server.js[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1J8f.png), I tried to access it in db.js[db.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvScq.png) and config.js[config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnY1r.png)

I tried this, it works but any better and easy way of doing it?.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from "path";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const envPath = path.resolve(path.dirname(__filename), "../../backend/.env");

dotenv.config({ path: envPath });

var password = process.env.password;

console.log(password);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use dotenv with ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620877/cant-use-dotenv-with-es6-modules)

Comment: See also https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to setup dotenv in every file. You have to execute dotenv.config() before importing `app` in server.js. for example:

This will work:

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
// Needs to executed first
dotenv.config();

// Then import other files
const { db } = require("./internal/db");



console.log(db);
```

Comment: I have a PASSWORD variable in .env, which is needed in db.js to connect to database. how can i do it?

Comment: How did you start the application? @DonaldReddyIndelu

Comment: nodemon server.js

Comment: See my edited answer @DonaldReddyIndelub

Comment: Got it, thank you @PrinceBillyGraham

Answer (score -2):

The code you've provided is a reasonable way to load environment variables from a specific `.env` file when you're not in the same directory as the file. However, there are some improvements you can make to enhance its readability and maintainability.

1. **Use `__dirname`**: Instead of constructing the `envPath` using `path.resolve(path.dirname(__filename), ...)`, you can directly use `__dirname` to get the directory of the current module. It's a built-in property that Node.js provides.

   ```js
   import dotenv from "dotenv";
   import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
   import path from "path";

   const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
   const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

   const envPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../backend/.env");

   dotenv.config({ path: envPath });

   var password = process.env.password;

   console.log(password);
   ```

   Using `__dirname` makes it more explicit and easier to understand.
2. **Error Handling**: It's a good practice to handle potential errors when loading environment variables from a file. If the `.env` file doesn't exist or if there are issues reading it, you should catch those errors and handle them appropriately.

   ```js
   import dotenv from "dotenv";
   import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
   import path from "path";
   import fs from "fs";

   const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
   const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
   const envPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../backend/.env");

   // Check if the .env file exists before trying to load it
   if (fs.existsSync(envPath)) {
     dotenv.config({ path: envPath });
     var password = process.env.password;
     console.log(password);
   } else {
     console.error(".env file not found");
   }
   ```

   This ensures that your code gracefully handles missing `.env` files.

By making these improvements, your code will be more organized and resilient to potential issues.